# Get pattern depends of input string

Tags: regex

Is it possible, and how should regex look like to get everything after the closing bracket or get everything if there are no brackets at all?

example:

possible input 1:

```
[12,45] some text
```

possible input 2:
some text

expected to get:

```
 some text
```

I found something like lookbehing conditional, and tried:

```
(?(?<=\])((?<=\])(.*))|(.*))
```

but didn't work.

This works for the input with brackets:

```
(?<=\])(.*)
```

And this works for input without brackets:

```
(.*)
```

but is it possible to get one expression to match both input cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This regex, you need `OR` aka `|`:

```
(?<=]\s|^)[\w\s]+
#      ^ 
#      |
#    there
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | [look behind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `]` | ] |
| `\s` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") |
| `|` | OR |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `[\w\s]+` | any character of: word characters (a-z, A- Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

### Online Demo

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l5g58K/1)

Comment: I don't know if there will be whitespace after closing brackets (if not, it's still acceptable), I added also recognition for diacritics in the text (in my particular language could be those kinds of signs, so I need to take this into consideration) and it works perfectly! 
THX
my new regex:
(?<=]|^)[\w\s\À-ž]+

Comment: Feel free to remove `\s` aka _white space_. There's no copyright©®™

Comment: Looks like east Europe, maybe Czech Republic? Poland?

Comment: Yes, Poland, and our special signs ą ę ć ś ł ź ;)

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the **sub** command from the `re` package:

#### Code:

```
import re

text = "[12,45] some text\nsome text"
output = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]\s?', '', text)
print(output)
```

#### Output:

```
some text
some text
```

Regex to **remove** the contents within and including the square brackets.

- `\[.*?\]\s?`
- `\[` = left square bracket
- `.*?` = zero or more characters (optional)
- `\]` = right square bracket
- `\s?` = space (optional)